# Delete Message after reaction | Discord JS

Tags: javascript, npm, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello I make this command :

```
module.exports = {
    name: "react",
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends a reaction",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.react('✅');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['✅'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
    };

    message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();

            if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                return message.delete();
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            return message.delete();
        });
        }
}
```

... to delete message on reaction.
But I want that, when my bot send a message, we can delete it with a reaction

If anyone can help me it will be very friendly !

Comment: Please provide the error if you are facing any that would help others to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

**I have manage to get this work like this**

```
module.exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
    
message.react('✅');

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['✅'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
            return message.delete();
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        return message.delete();
    });
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "react",
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends a reaction",
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how you got it working.